# Trim white space before text in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, whitespace, trim

Can't find the answer, I tried with what I found on this website and elsewhere but it never works.

Goal : to trim white spaces before and after a word giving in the field DIV.

Problem : everything works fine as long there is NO white space before a word ! There can already be text in the DIV of it can be an empty DIV where text can be inserted.

I tried in the javascript in the DIV like **trim(this)** but that doesn't work. Even inthe script itself I tried  **$.trim(editableObj.innerHTML)** , nor **editableObj.innerHTML.trim()**

Nothing works !

JS

```
<script>
function showEdit(editableObj) {
  $(editableObj).css("background", "#FFF");
}

function saveToDatabase(editableObj, column, linkmainid, nav, linkid) {
  $(editableObj).css("background", "#FFF url(loaderIcon.gif) no-repeat right");
  $.ajax({
    url: 'save'+nav+'.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: 'linkcat=' + column + '&linktitle=' + editableObj.innerHTML + '&linkmainid=' + linkmainid + '&action=' + nav + '&linkid=' + linkid,
    success: function(data) {
      $(editableObj).css("background", "#FDFDFD");

      window.location="/website/cms/menu.php";
    }
  });
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="navnew" contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'1','999999','navnew','111')" onClick="showEdit(this);"></div>
```

Comment: Have a look at the docs for [`.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim). Trim is called on the string with no parameters.

Comment: Your code is flawed.  For the URL, you'll want to use `encodeURIComponent()` around `nav`.  For your data, you can/should use a standard JavaScript object, and let jQuery encode the data for you.  Otherwise, data won't be escaped properly and will lead to other problems.

Comment: If you are purely interested in text (with no other html) try [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead of `innerHTML`

Answer (score 2):

```
var stringWithLeadingSpaces = "        hello world!"
var trimmedString = stringWithLeadingSpaces.trim();
console.log(trimmedString); //logs "hello world!"
```

[trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

Comment: Tried  var edithtml = editableObj.innerHTML;
   var edithtmltrim = edithtml.trim();
Didn't worked.

Comment: @FreeSpirit, define didn't work.... what console errors if any? What happened/didn't happen? I ask because the code as presented works: https://jsfiddle.net/euhge1g1/

Comment: @FreeSpirit-- so, if I try something similar to that on an HTML element in the console it works fine. Have you tried console logging `editableObj` and `editableObj.innerHTML` to make sure that are what you expect? If `editableObj` is a jQuery wrapped object, you'll need to unwrap it to access the `innerHTML` method...

Comment: @ jhon P : I don't see the "hello world" appearing in  jsfiddle.net/euhge1g1

Comment: @ Anied :  Has it to do something with the included script ?  I don't know what is the right one ! 
jquery-1.10.2.js
https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: @FreeSprit-- I just opened your fiddle and the "hello world" is definitely there at the very top of the console.  As for which jQuery version to choose, it depends on what you're trying to achieve.  I don't think you need jQuery UI-- probably the latest version of just jQuery would be fine, unless you need to support IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Add this snippet to your code:

```
String.prototype.trim = String.prototype.trim || function trim() { 
       return this.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, ''); };
```

Then, use:

```
var myValue = "  one, two, three    ".trim();
```

or

```
var myValue = "  one, two, three    ";
var myValueTrimmed = myValue.trim();
```

Comment: Where should I put the code String.prototype.trim ....  ?
After  $.ajax({ ?  That doesn't work. I did the rest with the **var** like in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Typing spaces into the content editable DIV inserts non breaking space characters. If you retrieve the content of `editableObj.innerHTML` these show up as sequences of the character entity string "&nbsp;". Naturally `String.prototype.trim` does *not* remove occurrences of "&nbsp;" because they are not white space text!

If you retrieve the content as `editableObj.textContent` the text returned contains actual non-break spaces with character code 0xA0.  `String.prototype.trim` does remove these.

Ultimately choose a trim method that suits your needs, depending on whether you want to save HTML or plain text in the database.